# Height of tabContainers in dojo

Tags: css, layout, dojo

I am using a Dojo tabContainer.
The quick question: do you *have to* specify the widget size in pixel in the CSS, if you are dealing with a Dojo container?
From what I am seeing, the only way to get a TabContainer to actually show is by giving it an absolute size via CSS.

**UPDATE:** I figured out that the elements `body` and `html` were missing the `height` attribute, and therefore it was computed to 0. So, now if I set them as 100% I will display the form... but, it will be huge! (as long as the page). The idea is to set its height to `auto`, so that it's "as long as it needs to be"... is that even possible?

In my HTML I have something like:

```
...
<body>
  <div id="loginForm"> </div>
</body>
...
```

I then have then in the code:

```
require(["app/widgets/LoginForm"], function( loginForm){
  // Create the "application" object, and places them in the right spot.
  loginForm = new LoginForm( {} , 'loginForm');
  loginForm.startup();
});
```

LoginForm is a simple template-based widget with the following template:

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="tabContainer" data-dojo-type="app.TabFading" data-dojo-props="tabPosition:'top'" style="height:100%">         

  <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-attach-point="loginPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Login'">
    <form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" data-dojo-attach-point="loginForm" method="POST">
      <label for="${id}_login">Login</label>
      <input name="login" id="${id}_login" data-dojo-attach-point="login" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="required:true"/>
      <label for="${id}_password">Password</label>  
      <input name="password" id="${id}_password0" data-dojo-attach-point="password" data-dojo-type="app.ValidationPassword" />
      <input type="submit" data-dojo-attach-point="button" data-dojo-type="app.BusyButton" label="Login!" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as basic as it gets:

```
#loginForm {
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;

 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;

 /*** Background Gradient - 2 declarations one for Firefox and one for Webkit ***/
 background:  -moz-linear-gradient(19% 75% 90deg,#FCFCFC, #CCCCCC);
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FCFCFC), to(#CCCCCC));

 /*** Shadow behind the box ***/
 -moz-box-shadow:0px -5px 300px #a9a0a0;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px -5px 300px #a9a0a0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  font: 9pt/1.5em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0  0;
}
```

The only way I have to make the TabContainer actually appear is to have `height:300px` in it -- otherwise, the computed height is 0.

Is this how it's meant to be? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you set the property `doLayout` to false on either the ContentPane or the TabContainer it should automatically size the height to the content.  The `doLayout` property of the dijit layout containers defaults to true, which then requires a specific height to be applied to it.

Comment: I cannot, cannot express my gratitude for this answer. Everybody please comment this UP UP UP. I wasted way too much time on this... really, thank you.

Comment: This is literally LIFE CHANGING. Where is this documented? It should definitely be more prominent in the dojo docs!

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!  This really should be documented better in the Dojo Docs

Comment: @streetlight You can find some documentation here. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/TabContainer-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Just set the tab container to doLayout="false"

Detail example is here : https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html#examples